# Material CardView real bottom Shadow Only android

Tags: android, kotlin, material-design

How to achieve this kind of shadow using Material CardView. The shadow is only at the bottom not any other side.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

app:cardElevation="10dp". Try this on your XML file

Comment: card elevation apply shadow on all side. But I want only at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

Remove elevation and add this xml as custom background of cardview.

```
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item>
   <shape>
    <padding android:top="0.5dp" android:right="0.5dp" android:bottom="1dp" 
    android:left="0.5dp" />
    <solid android:color="#10CCCCCC" />
    <corners android:radius="8dp" />
     </shape>
     </item>
     <item>
    <shape>
    <padding android:top="0.5dp" android:right="0dp" android:bottom="1dp" 
    android:left="0.5dp" />
      <solid android:color="#10CCCCCC" />
    <corners android:radius="7dp" />
     </shape>
     </item>
     <item>
    <shape>
    <padding android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:bottom="1dp" 
     android:left="1dp" />
    <solid android:color="#20CCCCCC" />
     <corners android:radius="6dp" />
     </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
    <shape>
    <padding android:top="0dp" android:right="0dp" android:bottom="1dp" 
     android:left="0dp" />
     <solid android:color="#30CCCCCC" />
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
    </shape>
   </item>
   <item>
   <shape>
    <padding android:top="0dp" android:right="0dp" android:bottom="1dp" 
     android:left="0dp" />
    <solid android:color="#40CCCCCC" />
    <corners android:radius="4dp" />
    </shape>
   </item>
   <item>
  <shape>
    <padding android:top="0dp" android:right="0dp" android:bottom="1dp" 
    android:left="0dp" />
    <solid android:color="#50CCCCCC" />
    <corners android:radius="3dp" />
    </shape>
    </item>
   <item>
    <shape>

    <padding android:top="0dp" android:right="0.1dp" android:bottom="0.5dp" 
   android:left="0.1dp" />
    <solid android:color="#60CCCCCC" />
    <corners android:radius="3dp" />
   </shape>
   </item>
   <item>
   <shape>
    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
      <corners android:radius="3dp" />
   </shape>
   </item>
```

Comment: As I asked in the question . I need real shadow like cardview not the one drawn with xml shapes.